# Eclipse Git(EGit) Remote : Invalid packet line header

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, egit

I'm trying to use Git on my server but i am not able to use it. I'm getting error when i try to push project to server. Here is the error.

**Error Message**

> An exception occurred during push on URI
>   ssh://Emre@88.247.25.9:7358/C:/Android Repository: Invalid packet line
>   header: Unab

**Exception Stack Trace**

```java
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Invalid packet line
 header: Unab   at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.readAdvertisedRefs(BasePackConnection.java:182)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshPushConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:327)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openPush(TransportGitSsh.java:152)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1173)   at
 org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:190)     at
 org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.ConfirmationPage$2.run(ConfirmationPage.java:206)
    at
 org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid packet line header: Unab   at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:193)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readString(PacketLineIn.java:138)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.readAdvertisedRefsImpl(BasePackConnection.java:195)
    at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackConnection.readAdvertisedRefs(BasePackConnection.java:176)
    ... 7 more
```

Does my ssh URI correct ?

`ssh://Emre@88.247.25.9:7358/C:/Android Repository`

Emre is my username. I'm using 7358 port. My project location is C:/Android Repository in server.

Comment: What happens when you push using the command line with the same URL?

Comment: I'm newbie on git. I don't know how can i push via command line. Can you give me any sample ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your ssh URL is invalid. Use this command to set remote URL.

```
git remote set-url origin <new_url>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the user did not have shell access.